# Is there a function that is opposite of paste() when editing (i.e. deleting characters from) column names of a matrix in r?

Tags: string, r, substring, paste, substr

I'm looking to remove the first character of every column name in a matrix.

```
mat1 <- matrix(seq(1:6), 2)
dimnames(mat1)[[2]] <- c("bA", "bB", "bC")


bA    bB    bC
1     2     3
4     5     6
```

into this:

```
A     B     C
1     2     3
4     5     6
```

I know with the `paste()` function, you can append to the column names; is there a function that does the opposite?

Comment: This has nothing to do with matrices. It's operating on `dimnames()` which is a character vector.

Answer (score 8):

substring is the appropriate function:

```
 dimnames(mat1)[[2]] <- substring(dimnames(mat1)[[2]], first=2)

 mat1
     A B C
[1,] 1 3 5
[2,] 2 4 6
```

Comment: Note that you can use the expression `colnames(mat1)` instead of `dimnames(mat1)[[2]]` here, on both sides of the assignment (as was used in the answer that was just deleted).

Answer (score 4):

Besides the `substring` approach you can use regex methods:

```
?regex
  colnames(mat1) <- sub('^\\.', "", colnames(mat1) ) # removes first letter
  # the next one removes lower-case letters which for some reason Jilber has already posted but  deleted
  colnames(mat1) <- sub("[a-z]", "", colnames(mat1) )
```

If there were "separators" you can also use `strsplit`:

```
?strsplit
 colnames(mat1) <- sapply( strsplit( c("b_A", "b_B", "b_C"), "_"), "[", 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

`stri_sub` function from `stringi` package.

```
require(stringi)
stri_sub(c("aA","bB","aC"),2)
## [1] "A" "B" "C"
```